# lock dock icons on ADW launcher

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, adw.launcher

Does somebody knows how can I lock the ADW launcher dock icons so with that I can't move or delete any of those?

Why I want that: Because sometimes I click on an icon on the dock and ADW moves it out of the dock. The same behaviour like I was holding that icon, but without holding it. It's very annoying.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this precise behavior exists in ADW at the moment. However, you can [lock your desktop entirely](http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/wiki/CompleteGuideToADW#Lock_Desktop) if you want to, which prevents you from moving any of the icons or adding new icons (or widgets). You'll have to unlock it whenever you want add widgets/icons but it's only three clicks (`Menu button->More->(un)Lock Desktop`).